# Google guava LoadingCache: when should cache.cleanup() be called

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I am using LoadingCache in my project.I have  configured a RemovalListener  and CahceLoader  for the cache.

```
    LoadingCache<Key, value> cache = cache = (LoadingCache<Key, value>) CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder().initialCapacity(50).maximumSize(500).expireAfterAccess(4, HOURS)
            .removalListener(new RemovalHander())
            .build(new CacheLoader<Key, value>() {
                @Override
                public Value load(Key request) {
                    return loadCache(request);
                }

            });
```

I am facing concurrency issue with this cache in below scenario:

- On request for Key1, cache is populated with Value1
- Cache is not accessed for Key1 for next 4 hours
- When 4 hours are passed, Key1 is marked  as expired
- After  4  hours, request comes  to access Key1
- On request for Key1(received  in **request-thread**) after 4 
  hours,LoadingCache finds Key1 as  expired so it initiates a new thread(call 
  it **cleanup-thread)** to  do cleanup of cache for Key1  and in **request- 
  thread** it tries load the fresh data for Key1
- As both operations remove/fetch are performed for same key i.e. Key1, 
  **request-thread** finds there is already an entry while **cleanup-thread** 
  is  removing the data.

So, in short,  RemovalHander races with the CacheLoader for Key1. 
I want to avoid  above case and thinking to call `cleanup()`  method of `LoadingCache`.

Can you please suggest on following points :

1. When should the cleanup() method be called? Periodically using some **SchedulerService** or on every request for an entry in cache?
2. Is there any better way to solve  above problem?
3. Is their any better replacement of GuavaCache?

Comment: It's unclear, but sounds like you're saying that the `RemovalHander` races with the `CacheLoader` to see some shared state. If you need to have the removal handler synchronously called prior to the load, you could use Caffeine's `CacheWriter`. In regards to `cleanUp`, it is mostly for testing or should be called periodically but wouldn't fix a race if that's the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks  updated post to make  it more clear.

Comment: Usually the race is okay, but if not then you’d have to handle the race somehow or consider switching to Caffeine.

Comment: Are you saying the cache is returning expired data? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: @shmosel I think he needs the removal listener to complete before the loader starts, which isn’t supported by Guava

Comment: What does `RemovalHandler` do?

Comment: @Ben Manes You understood my question correctly. You are suggesting to use  caffeine but I read its  documentation and  cleanup policy looks  completely similar to Guava cache: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Cleanup

On a side note, I just noticed you are the same Ben who worked on caffeine development. :)

Comment: @shmosel: RemovalHandler do some clean-up work e.g. closing open subscription from where I am getting data to populate cache.

Comment: I also worked on Guava’s so I know its limitations . You should look at https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer

Comment: @Ben Manes: Cool, thanks. I will take  a look  at Caffeine :)

Answer (score 0):

I know its being so late to give reply to this thread, but I have some findings which may help others. Recently I am doing work with CacheBuilder and I am using Guava library (25.1) for my implementaion.

As mentioned by @G.G. that the removal operation and loading operations are being done in two separate thread due to which race condition is appearing, I have seen that Guava cache actually runs these two methods synchronously. i.e on query with expired key, cache will first call this removal listener and then only it comes to the main thread. Here is the sample code -

```
private LoadingCache<String, String> cache;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CacheBuilderDemo2 cbd = new CacheBuilderDemo2();
    
    RemovalListener<String, String> listener = new RemovalListener<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, String> n){
            System.out.println("Came to remove for " + n.getKey());
            if (n.wasEvicted()) {
                String cause = n.getCause().name();
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() +"]" + "Removal " + cause);
                cbd.cache.invalidate(n.getKey());
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() +"]" + "Invalidate happened...");
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    CustomCacheLoader cL = cbd.new CustomCacheLoader();
    cbd.cache = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .removalListener(listener)
            .build(cL);
    
    cbd.cache.put("a", "Old value for a");
    try {
        System.out.println(cbd.cache.get("a"));
        Thread.sleep(100);

        System.out.println(cbd.cache.get("a"));
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class CustomCacheLoader extends CacheLoader<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String load(String key) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() +"]" + "Came to fetch... " + key);
        return "New value for " + key;
    }

}
```

And following is the response  -

```
Old value for a
Came to remove for a
[main]Removal EXPIRED
[main]Invalidate happened...
[main]Came to fetch... a
New value for a
```

This behavioral difference could be due to the version mismatch. Thanks for the read .